# Does set needed in provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have provider that I build by learning from course, and there is `set` variables if I remove it nothing change and everything works fine but I'm afraid in future something will go error.

Here is my code:

```
  class SimilarMovieProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<SimilarMovieModel> _similarMovie = [];
  bool _isLoading = true;

  List<SimilarMovieModel> get similarMovie => _similarMovie;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  set similarMovie(List<SimilarMovieModel> _similarMovie) {
    _similarMovie = similarMovie;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set isLoading(bool _isLoading) {
    _isLoading = isLoading;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future getSimilarMovie(movieId) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    try {
      List<SimilarMovieModel> similarMovie =
          await Http().getSimilarMovie(movieId);
      _similarMovie = similarMovie;
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned it doesn't change anything. You just switch from using a setter to using a method to update your instance.

Comment: Thats correct. You may look at the difference between setters and methods in dart.